# Function to sort an array of number

Tags: php, algorithm

I want to sort an array given, for example:

"1; -2; 3.5; 4"

But my function doesn't work and if i try var_dump() i only got the numbers unsorted. 
Could anyone please help me to understand ?

I put this numbers in example, but if anyone could explain me how to do also if i don't want to put any numbers within my function and to compile directly, for example with that command :

-> php insertion_sort.php "1; -2; 3.5; 4".

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
function swap($a, $b) {
    $tmp;

    $tmp = $a;
    $a = $b;
    $b = $tmp; 
}

function insertion_sort($array) {
    $array = array(1, -2, 3.5, 4);
    $length = count($array); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
        $i_min = $i; 
        for ($j = $i+1; $j < $length; $j++) {
            if  ($array[$j] < $array[$i_min]) {
                $i_min = $j;
                swap($j, $i_min);
            }   
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the sort functions that PHP already has builtin

Comment: simply you can use sort($array) to get a sorted output.. But you are looking for sorted output without using PHP inbuilt function?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell you, The purpose  is to create my own function

Comment: You have a function with a parameter. Your code instantly destroys the parameter contents on its first line of the function?

Comment: Oh and you never call `insertion_sort()`

Answer (score 0):

This if I remember correctly is a bubble sort

```
function my_sort(&$array)
{
    for ($i=0; $i<count($array)-1; $i++){
        for ($j=0; ($j<count($array)-$i-1); $j++){
            if( $array[$j] > $array[$j+1]) {
                // swap
                $t           = $array[$j];
                $array[$j]   = $array[$j+1];
                $array[$j+1] = $t;
            }
        }
    }
}


$array = [1,4, -2, 3.5];

my_sort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have understand what was wrong with my code